# unable to create instance with gcloud command

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to create an instance in Google Compute getting an error.

```
 gcloud compute instances create 'my-instance'
For the following instances:
 - [my-instance]
choose a zone:
 [1] asia-east1-b
 [2] asia-east1-c
 [3] asia-east1-a
 [4] europe-west1-c
 [5] europe-west1-b
 [6] europe-west1-d
 [7] us-central1-f
 [8] us-central1-a
 [9] us-central1-c
 [10] us-central1-b
 [11] us-east1-b
 [12] us-east1-d
 [13] us-east1-c
Please enter your numeric choice:  11

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'xxxxx@project.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.
```

The resource isn't listed in the IAM or ServiceAccount lists.

Answer (score 1):

[First assure you have initialized your gcloud account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing)
  ... issue

```
gcloud auth login
```

then as it explains paste into a browser (which you have previously logged into Google) and put browser generated token back onto the command line ...  once its happy you are done ... go ahead and launch your cluster now ... if you wish to get fancy by using a service account (not necessary) do its setup then issue

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account    # optional
```